# Chrome notification with rails - 400 UnauthorizedRegistration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-cloud-messaging, web-push, chrome-gcm

I`m using Rails and https://github.com/zaru/webpush gem and have configured things according to this guide 
https://rossta.net/blog/web-push-notifications-from-rails.html

I manage to register ServiceWorker and get subscription. I save it like this in controller

```
endpoint = params[:subscription][:endpoint]
p256dh = params[:subscription][:keys][:p256dh]
auth = params[:subscription][:keys][:auth]

current_user.gcm_endpoint = endpoint
current_user.gcm_p256dh = p256dh
current_user.gcm_auth = auth
```

Later I send the message like this:

```
message = {
    title: "Title",
    body: "This is a test notification",
    icon: "images/my-128.png"
}

Webpush.payload_send(
    endpoint: current_user.gcm_endpoint,
    message: JSON.generate(message),
    p256dh: current_user.gcm_p256dh,
    auth: current_user.gcm_auth,
    ttl: 600,
    api_key: "<MY API KEY>"
)
```

I have configured and activated account on Google Console. I have turned on GCM API and added a correct key. But no matter what I do, I receive this 400 error code. And I have no stats in Google console - as if no calls are made to my API call.

Comment: See [this](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6310037?hl=en)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the key itself. Need to generate it using a separate Firebase control panel. [Here](https://console.firebase.google.com/?pli=1) With that key my code works well.